# How can I obtain all combinations of my list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-itertools

I am attempting to create an array with all the possible combinations of two numbers.

My array is `[0, 17.1]`

I wish to obtain all the possible combinations of these two values in a list of 48 elements long, both of which can be repeated.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
array = [0, 17.1]
combo_wr = combinations_with_replacement(array, 48)
print(len(list(combo_wr)))
```

I have attempted to make use of `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to create something which looks like the following -> `combo_wr = combinations_with_replacement(array, 48)`.

When I print the length of this I would expect a much larger number but I am only getting 49 combinations of these numbers. Where am I going wrong or what other functions would work better to get all the possible combinations, order does not matter in the instance.

Below is what I have tried so far for reproducibility

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> array = [0, 17.1]
>>> combo_wr = combinations_with_replacement(array, 48)
>>> print(len(list(combo_wr)))
49
```

Comment: combinations considers order irrelevent, you are getting all combinations of how many elements are `17.1` which goes from 0 (they are all 0) to 48 (all of them) so there are 49 combinations, do you want `permutations` or `product(array, repeat=48)` instead?

Comment: Your list would be spectacularly long if it were a list of all 48 position combinations of either 0 or 17.1 - effectively 48 bits, so 2^48, about 2.8 * 10^14 elements.

Comment: @Grismar that would be product, combinations is when the ordering is irrelevant, pretty sure 49 is the correct number of options here.

Comment: Ah, you're right of course. I was thrown off by OP being confused by that number, suggesting they were actual going for what I suggested, but I agree that the terms used suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Grismar you could be correct yes. I wish to get all of them but is it possible to narrow down those of which would satisfy say the summated value of >= 250?

Comment: Apologies for any confusion in my terminology. I do wish to  get the product I assume in this case then

Comment: @AidanDonnelly you may want to address Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's point first - are you in fact after combinations (of which there really are only 49), or are you after permutations, in which case a restriction of requiring a sum of over 250 still means you will have a mind-boggling number of results? (any 15 or over 17.1 elements would get you over 250, so it only reduces the space to 2^33)

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here, that requires all permutations of those two numbers over 48 positions? It seems like you're dealing with an XY problem here.

Comment: Ultimately I am trying to find a best fit of when I can run a pump to fill a reservoir. I have tried a number of numerical solvers but I feel like they aren't working on all possibilities. I have a number of constraints such as to keep within a min and max level and delivery a minimum volume for the cheapest cost. So this is why I am looking all possible solutions that would meet then requirements.

Comment: Numerical solvers typically won't work on all possibilities, as brute-forcing it would take impossibly long - however, as long as the solver you're using is configured appropriately, you should still end up with reasonable results. I'm afraid I can only recommend going back to the solver (or picking another), since brute-forcing all solutions is next to impossible and the alternative is writing your own solver - which will be far harder than understanding why the current one doesn't get you the right results (or perhaps it does, and you don't see why)

Answer (score 0):

a sequence of `48` numbers each chosen from 2 different options gives a search space of `2^48` which is `281.4` trillion.

An added constrant that the sum of the numbers should be larger than 250, then with `[0,17.1]` means at least 15 of the elements must be `17.1` so you reduce your search space by `48 choose 15` which is 1 trillion, I.E. not enough to make much of a difference.

If you set the first (or last) 15 elements to `17.1` then it would reduce the search space to choosing the rest of the elements so `2^(58-15) = 2^33` which is 8.6 billion but I'm not sure that is the constraint you actually want or if that is still small enough to be useful.

So code that produces the results you asked for is not likely to help you.

### But if you still *wanted* help generating those trillions of combinations

to clarify what the different options available to you:

- `itertools.product` gives every possible sequence of heads and tails
- `itertools.combinations` gives the unordered subsets of a given length
- `itertools.permutations` gives all ways of reordering the given sequence, or ordering of all subsets of a given length
- `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` gives all subsets where the number of repetitions of different options is unique, for 2 element input this would be like "after n coin flips what are the sequences where the number of heads is unique"

`permutations` and `combinations` don't make sense with `len(array)==2` and `r=48` since they are about subsets and `product` will do a lot more redundancy than you want.

> order does not matter in the instance.

If this is the case then it is possible you are just expecting more combos then there are.

> I wish to get all of them but is it possible to narrow down those of which would satisfy say the summated value of >= 250

ok so then you can get every unique value for the sum of elements with `combinations_with_replacements` then do `permutations` on that

```
array = [0, 17.1]
reps = 48
lower_bound = 250
upper_bound = float("inf") # you might have an upper bound, if not you can remove this from the condition below or leave it as inf
for combo in combinations_with_replacement(array, reps):
    if lower_bound <= sum(combo) <= upper_bound:
        # this combo of 'number of elements that are 17.1` meets criteria for further investigation
        for perm in permutations(combo):
            do_thing(perm)
```

although this still ends up visiting a ton of duplicate entries since `permutations` of a sequence with a lot of duplicate entries will swap elements that are equal and give the same entries so we can do better.

First the `combinations_with_replacement` is really only communicating how many of each element we are dealing with so we can just do `for k in range(reps)` to get that info, and then want every permutation that has exactly `k` repeats of the second element in `array` - which happens to be equivalent to choosing `k` indices to set to that.

So we can use `combinations(range(reps), k)` to get a set of indices to set to the second element and this I believe is the smallest set of possible sequences you would have to check to meet the "sum is greater than `250` requirement.

```
reps = 48
def isSummationValidCombo(summation):
    return summation >= 250

for k in range(reps):
    summation = array[1] *k + array[0] * (reps-k)
    if not isSummationValidCombo(summation):
        continue
    for indices_of_sequence_to_set_to_second_element in combinations(range(reps), k):
        # each combination of k inices to set to the higher value
        seq = [array[0]]*reps
        for idx in indices_of_sequence_to_set_to_second_element:
            seq[idx] = array[1]
        do_thing(seq)
```

this would leave your number of combinations as 280 trillion compared to the 281 trillion that would be hit by `product` so you will probably need to figure out other techniques to reduce search space

Comment: Note that from OP's comments, it's clear they misspoke and are actually after permutations - positions matter.

Comment: ok now it probably actually helps with the added info from comments

Comment: Checking that a value is less than or equal to the maximum value the type can represent seems superfluous? This code ignores the fact that it may run forever though, given that `do_thing()` is supposed to compute something a bit more serious, going by OP's comments - so although you seem to be correct in explaining how to code it, you're sidestepping the fact that the solution won't actually work.

Comment: how would that code have run forever? both loops are bounded by how many repetitions they can iterate - or do you mean that it would just take unreasonably long time? I always forget that `permutations` doesn't handle duplicate entries efficiently so I added another version that accounts for that although there may be a simpler way of representing it.

Comment: "Forever", for all practical intents and purposes, as the program would be started, and would never see completion, in anyone's lifetime. Certainly unreasonable, practically it would never complete. You seem to be ignoring the added comments from OP, shedding light on the type of application they need this for.  As their problem is under-constrained, you end up in ridiculously large search spaces for brute force and the approach you're suggesting ignores that.

Comment: Well I'm not ignoring it anymore but I certainly don't have enough info about the actual problem or enough experience with numerical solvers to give useful advice, was a fun exercise to construct a solution **that answers what was asked** whether or not it was what was wanted/needed.